# How to get all the possible input parameters for python requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to find the documentation for python `requests` method, but it seems like this is a hidden method. [Documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/)

For instance: when I do:
`response = requests("GET", URL, data=test, timeout=60)`,
where can I get all the possible input parameters?

In fact I cannot even find the documentation for the `requests` method, it seems like it has been deprecated and split into `.get`, `.post` etc.

Comment: Seems like the correct word I was looking for is developer interface: `http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/`

Comment: You cannot call `requests`. `requests` is a module. Did you mean `response = requests.request("GET", URL, data=test, timeout=60)`? If so, just do `help(requests.request)` to get comprehensive information

Answer (score 4):

If you're not sure of what a module does, and can't find the documents (which you can certainly find for `requests`, by the way), you can use python `dir` function:

```
dir(requests)
```

This will print all attributes (modules, functions, members) under this object. And in python, everything is an object, so you can do this to any unknown (or known) object. You can go further to print the type of the attributes:

```
print("\n".join(['{} : {}'.format(name, type(getattr(requests,name))) for name in dir(requests)]))
```

And here's a *slice* of the return:

```
__path__ : <type 'list'>
__title__ : <type 'str'>
__version__ : <type 'str'>
adapters : <type 'module'>
api : <type 'module'>
auth : <type 'module'>
delete : <type 'function'>
exceptions : <type 'module'>
get : <type 'function'>
```

Each of these you can call by `requests.[name]`, e.g. `requests.get`

If you want to find the arguments to function, you can do:

```
requests.get.__code__.co_varnames
```

Beware though, `**kwargs` will register as one argument and it is virtually impossible to find what it is without going into the code or documents.

Some functions are well documented, in that case. you can do `func.__doc__`. For instance, `requests.get` calls `requests.request` and if you do `requests.request.__doc__` there's a good document of what everything is:

```
Constructs and sends a :class:`Request <Request>`.
Returns :class:`Response <Response>` object.

:param method: method for the new :class:`Request` object.
:param url: URL for the new :class:`Request` object.
:param params: (optional) Dictionary or bytes to be sent in the query string for the :class:`Request`.
:param data: (optional) Dictionary, bytes, or file-like object to send in the body of the :class:`Request`.
:param json: (optional) json data to send in the body of the :class:`Request`.
:param headers: (optional) Dictionary of HTTP Headers to send with the :class:`Request`.
:param cookies: (optional) Dict or CookieJar object to send with the :class:`Request`.
:param files: (optional) Dictionary of ``'name': file-like-objects`` (or ``{'name': ('filename', fileobj)}``) for multipart encoding upload.
:param auth: (optional) Auth tuple to enable Basic/Digest/Custom HTTP Auth.
:param timeout: (optional) How long to wait for the server to send data
    before giving up, as a float, or a (`connect timeout, read timeout
    <user/advanced.html#timeouts>`_) tuple.
:type timeout: float or tuple
:param allow_redirects: (optional) Boolean. Set to True if POST/PUT/DELETE redirect following is allowed.
:type allow_redirects: bool
:param proxies: (optional) Dictionary mapping protocol to the URL of the proxy.
:param verify: (optional) if ``True``, the SSL cert will be verified. A CA_BUNDLE path can also be provided.
:param stream: (optional) if ``False``, the response content will be immediately downloaded.
:param cert: (optional) if String, path to ssl client cert file (.pem). If Tuple, ('cert', 'key') pair.

Usage::

  >>> import requests
  >>> req = requests.request('GET', 'http://httpbin.org/get')
  <Response [200]>
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, I think OP is asking for how to find out the possible `args` and `kwargs` for a method.

Comment: @Idlehands You're right, if it's just the `args`, that's easy to find by `requests.get.__code__.co_varnames`. But `**kwargs` are virtually impossible to find without document.